# Diferenças entre Natural Join e Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Que características diferenciam uma consulta realizada com o uso de `Natural Join` de outra com o uso de `Inner Join`? Existe alguma questão relacionada a desempenho ou qualquer outra condição que me leve a escolher uma em detrimento da outra?

Para o exemplo abaixo, teríamos as seguintes consultas:

```
select livro.nome_livro, editora.nome_editora from livro natural join editora
```

ou

```
select livro.nome_livro, editora.nome_editora from livro
inner join editora on editora.codigo_editora = livro.codigo_editora
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O `NATURAL JOIN` é só um facilitador. Ele não é mais rápido ou faz nada melhor, ele apenas permite uma sintaxe mais curta se a junção é simples, o seu exemplo ilustra bem isto. Ambos fazem exatamente a mesma coisa da mesma forma mas a primeira é mais fácil de escrever.

O nome é assim porque esta é a forma mais natural de fazer um `INNER JOIN` simples.

Como dá para perceber não é possível produzir resultados com expressões mais complexas usando a forma natural.

Se o `*` for usado para pegar os campos nas tabelas com `NATURAL JOIN` as colunas de mesmo nome não serão mostradas repetidas no resultado.

[Artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A minha dúvida é: Se esse método impacta no desempenho?

Comment: Como eu disse na primeira linha, não. Claro que se você comprar com coisas comparáveis, comparar uma forma com outra que faz outra coisa é claro que tem diferença, mas aí o problema é não saber comparar.

Answer (score -2):

O `NATURAL JOIN` deve ser evitado pois ele assume que o predicado qualificador (expressão que resulta em `true` ou `false` e será utilizada pelo banco para comparação em cada registro da tabela) consiste em todas as colunas que possuem o mesmo alias em ambas as tabelas. Por exemplo, pode ocorrer de colunas adicionais serem adicionadas em uma tabela e por acaso elas terem o mesmo alias, alterando o resultado da query.

De sempre preferência ao `INNER JOIN` ao invés do `NATURAL_JOIN`.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Engraçado quem votou menos, manja bastante viu